# Oracle whitespaces bug

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have noticed a weird bug in our Oracle database as we are moving from one database (Oracle 11.2.0.3.0) to another database (Oracle 11.2.4.0). Database servers are in different data center with different operating systems and support teams. So the version is not the only thing that has changed.

So, this is the bug I am facing: When I execute this little SQL statement I get different results:

```
SELECT 'hello' FROM DUAL;
```

On the old database the output is: `"hello"`
On the new database the output is: `"hello                           "`

Where are these whitespaces coming from?

### UPDATE:

I am using TOAD for Oracle in version 12.10.0.30.

I have checked this parameters for both databases, but could not find any differences (except, of course, the version):

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;
SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters;
SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters;
SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters;
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;
```

Then I have checked this and found no differences:

```
DESC DUAL;
```

The next test I did was:

```
SELECT dummy FROM DUAL;
```

And the result for both databases was:`X`

Next test:

```
SELECT '|' || 'hello' || '|' FROM DUAL;
```

Result old database:`"|hello|"`
Result new database:`"|hello|                                                                                         "`

And another test:

```
SELECT '|' || dummy || '|' || 'Hello' || '|' FROM DUAL;
SELECT '|' || dummy || '|' FROM DUAL;
SELECT '|' || 'Hello' || '|' FROM DUAL;
```

And the results:
`"|X|Hello|"`
`"|X|"`
`"|Hello|                                                                                         "`
Interestingly it works for the first SQL, but the third one is filled up with whitespaces again.

### SQL*Plus

I have installed SQL*Plus on the same laptop TOAD is running.
Old database:

```
SQL> select dummy from dual;
D
-
X
SQL> select 'dummy' from dual;
'DUMM
-----
dummy
SQL> SELECT dump('hello') FROM DUAL;
DUMP('HELLO')
---------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=5: 104,101,108,108,111
```

New database:

```
SQL> select dummy from dual;
D
-
X
SQL> select 'dummy' from dual;
'DUMMY'
--------------------------------
dummy
SQL> SELECT dump('hello') FROM DUAL;
DUMP('HELLO')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=5: 104,101,108,108,111
```

### Solution

DB Parameter *.cursor_sharing was "EXACT" on the old database and "FORCE" on the new database. So we will have to change it to "EXCACT" too.

Comment: The white spaces could be in your application.  Try `select '|' || 'hello' || '|' from dual`.

Comment: How are you running the query?

Comment: To explain Gordon's and Kaushik's comments: If you use a front-end application like SQL Developer or Toad etc., THEY may be adding the spaces, not Oracle Database. (SQL Developer and Toad do **no such thing**, but we don't know what you do, actually, use). Gordon's suggested query will prove that any spaces, if they are added, are added after the closing pipe character (`|`) - you still won't know WHO is doing that, but you will know there's nothing wrong with 'hello'. That padding most likely may come from a column declared CHAR(20) or similar, instead of VARCHAR2.

Comment: try: desc dual;  This should be pointing to sys.dual.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have made an update of my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have SQL*Plus. Maybe I can install it later.
The problem originally occurred on a Java Program, so it is not a TOAD-specific problem.
I am using the same TOAD for both databases. So I assume it has to do with the server, not the client.

Comment: Do you see a difference when runing `SELECT dump('hello') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: The output of  `SELECT dump('hello') FROM DUAL;` is:
`Typ=96 Len=5: 104,101,108,108,111`

Comment: I have tested with SQL*Plus, please see my update, thank you.

Comment: Source of the problem was found: DB Parameter *.cursor_sharing was "EXACT" on the old database and "FORCE" on the new database.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the literal string `hello` is being interpreted as a `CHAR(26)` data type (which would be padded with spaces to be 26 characters long) instead of a `VARCHAR2(4000)` data type.  Since you are selected from the `DUAL` table, it must be something strange in the environment variables or or tools you are issuing the query from.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have made an update of my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Just messing around with this, and found that if you mess with the NLS_LANG settings on the client (from linux, probably the same for windows) I get different results (at least as it displays):

1. No NLS_LANG env variable set:

> SQL> select 'hello' from dual;
>
> ```
> 'HELL
> -----
> hello
> ```

2. export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8

> SQL> select 'hello' from dual;
>
> ```
> 'HELLO'
> ---------------
> hello
> ```

I'm guessing that it has to do with multibyte charset, but note that the length function for both still returns 5.

So check on your new setup to make sure your NLS setup is correct.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**:

I logged into Oracle to run your liveSQL test, and I do NOT get the spacing you see.  I think you may be opening the csv in Excel after downloading.  I opened in a text editor (V) and dumped the hex for the example you gave that supposedly has padding, and it does not:

```
00000000  27 7C 27 7C 7C 27 48 45 4C 4C 4F 27 7C 7C 27 7C    '|'||'HELLO'||'|
00000010  27 0A 7C 68 65 6C 6C 6F 7C 0A                      '.|hello|.
```

The dots above are newlines (0A).  There is no whitespace padding going on that I can find.

Your issue isn't reproducible (at least not in my environment or from liveSQL).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have made an update of my original post.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post.  So your client is the same for all tests? (all tests running same Toad on the same machine)

Comment: Yes, it is the same client for all test.
I am pretty sure meanwhile there is a bug since 11.2.0.4.0, because I could reproduce the error on Oracles LiveSQL.

Comment: I am really sorry, this was my fault, it isn't reproduceable on the live system... don't know what I have seen in my editor, maybe it's time for a break, sorry!

Comment: Ok, it happens to us all!  If my answer was helpful, please accept it, thanks